# Unable to link library with test binaries in cmake

Tags: c++, c, build, msbuild, cmake

I can't figure out how to link my static library with my test binaries using cmake on Windows. What am I doing wrong?

The structure of the project is like below

```
MyProject
  - build
  - include
    - catch
      - *.h
    - MyProject
      - *.h
  - src
    - *.c
  - test
    - *.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
```

And the CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED ( VERSION 3.3.1 )

SET ( NAME_LIB     "myproject" )
SET ( NAME_TEST    "test_myproject" )
SET ( PATH_BUILD   "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build" )
SET ( PATH_INCLUDE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" )
SET ( PATH_SOURCE  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src" )
SET ( PATH_TEST    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test" )

FILE ( GLOB SOURCES_LIB  "${PATH_SOURCE}/*.c" "${PATH_SOURCE}/*.cpp" )
FILE ( GLOB SOURCES_TEST "${PATH_TEST}/*.c" "${PATH_TEST}/*.cpp" )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ("${PATH_INCLUDE}")

ADD_LIBRARY( ${NAME_LIB} STATIC "${SOURCES_LIB}" )
ADD_EXECUTABLE ( ${NAME_TEST} "${SOURCES_TEST}" )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( ${NAME_TEST} "${PATH_BUILD}/${NAME_LIB}" )
```

Creating the visual studio project using cmake goes okay, but when I try to build the solution using msbuild I get the following error.

```
(Link target) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'myproject.obj' [D:\Source\myproject\build\test_myproject.vcxproj]
```

---

Error when specifying the library name instead of the absolute path.

```
test_myproject.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl myproject_parse(char const *)" (?myproject_parse@@YAHPBD@Z
) referenced in function _main [D:\Source\myproject\build\test_myproject.vcxproj]
D:\Source\myproject\build\Debug\test_myproject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [D:\Source\myproject\build\test_
myproject.vcxproj]
```

Comment: you seem to be mixing C and C++, so you have to make sure that  `myproject_parse` is no subject to C++ name mangling

Comment: could you please use [dumpbin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y05bd5.aspx) to output the symbols in myproject.lib such as `dumpbin /headers myproject.lib` and make sure the 'parse' symbol is listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try linking your library by target name, also maybe make sure the sources for the lib contain the files you expect, the other possibility is that no symbols are compiled

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( ${NAME_TEST} ${NAME_LIB} )
```

Comment: Not using an absolute path gives a linker error (unresolved external symbol).

Comment: unresolved external symbol is a much better error (from diagnosis point of view), please give me the complete error message

Comment: I updated the original post with information about the linker error

Comment: @ThomasDoyle, i noticed you accepted this, have you resolved your build problems?

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer since the linker issue was the actual problem. Since I mixed c and cpp the identifiers were mangled and forcing CXX solved that problem.